# How do I take a picture/photo using a camera on windows phone/desktop

Tags: c#, camera, win-universal-app

I would like to make an app that takes pictures that I can save to file or display to screen but am having trouble finding where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend creating a c# [Universal Windows App](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/universal-windows-platform-vs.aspx) if you are targeting phone or desktop.

To take a picture you can use [LowLagPhotoCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.lowlagphotocapture.aspx) to get a [SoftwareBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn887358)

```
    public async Task<SoftwareBitmap> takePhotoToSoftwareBitmap()
    {
        //initialize mediacapture with default camera
        var mc = new MediaCapture();
        await mc.InitializeAsync();

        //create low lag capture and take photo
        var lowLagCapture = await mc.PrepareLowLagPhotoCaptureAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateUncompressed(MediaPixelFormat.Bgra8));
        var photo = await lowLagCapture.CaptureAsync();

        //convert to displayable format
        SoftwareBitmap displayableImage;
        using (var frame = photo.Frame)
        {
            displayableImage = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(photo.Frame.SoftwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
        }

        return displayableImage;
    }
```

To see how to use (Save/Display/Edit) a SoftwareBitmap see the [Imaging How-To](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/imaging)

For more Windows camera documentation see [GitHub Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples) or [MediaCapture How-To](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-mediacapture)